# Retrieve all files created by a task to my local folder

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, google-drive

I'm exporting a map to my drive using the GEE python API, I'm looking for a way to retreive all the created files automatically to a local folder.

my current code create a image on my drive :

```py
def download_to_disk(country_code, year):
    """download the tile to the GEE disk"""
    file_name = 'alerts_' + country_code + '_' + year
    task_config = {
        'image':alerts,
        'description':file_name,
        'scale': 30,
        'region':country,
        'maxPixels': 1e10
    }
    
    task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**task_config)
    task.start()
```

Is there a way to retrieve the files created by this very task automatically using only the Python API ?

Comment: where does the variable `service` come from? I think your question is related to GDrive Python API and not GEE

Comment: It was just a bad copy-paste from the documentation. I realized my question wasn't super clear so I edited it. I pretty sure it's basic usage I just didn't find the appropriate documentation or example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after crawling a bit on the internet I found a workaround :

It's impossible to retreive a file from Gdrive with a task name or a filename are they are all identify with their unique ID.

Solution is to create a function that crawls into your files in your drive and select thoses corresponding to your task. in my case it look like :

```py
import ee

class gdrive(object):

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.initialize = ee.Initialize()
        self.credentials = ee.Credentials()
        self.service = discovery.build(serviceName='drive', version='v3', cache_discovery=False, credentials=self.credentials)

    def get_files(self, file_name):
        """ look for the file_name patern in my Gdrive files and retreive a list of Ids"""
        
        items = self.get_items()
        files = []
        for item in items:
            if (file_name in item['name']):
                files.append({'id':item['id'], 'name': item['name']})
                
        return files
```

then in the same `gdrive` object I created a function that retreive all my selected files from my drive to my local path.

```py
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

class gdrive(object):
    # [...] som code

    def download_files(self, files, local_path):
        service = self.service
        
        for fId in files:
            request = service.files().get_media(fileId=fId['id'])
            fh = io.BytesIO()
            downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                #print('Download %d%%.' % int(status.progress() * 100))
            
            fo = open(local_path+fId['name'], 'wb')
            fo.write(fh.getvalue())
            fo.close()
```

hope that it will help someone